# fraction multiplication with square root as the numerator

Tags: fractions

Can anyone explain how did the author arrived at the answer?

I can do multiplication of fractions like 1/2 * 1/3 etc... but I stumbled at this question

$$3/5 * \sqrt(3)/2 = 3/10 \sqrt3$$

Comment: Your formatting is off. In the answer, is the $10$ in the numerator or denominator?

Comment: $2\times 5 = 10$

Comment: What author? What answer?

Comment: 10 is the denominator

Comment: To make stacked fractions, use \frac, so \frac{3}{10} gives $\frac {3}{10}$.  You don't need the braces for a single character.  Similarly, if you put braces around the stuff that goes under the square root sign, the top bar extends to cover, so \sqrt{(3)} gives $\sqrt {(3)}$  In this case you are just multiplying $\frac 35$ by $\frac 12$ and the $\sqrt 3$ goes along for the ride.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{3}{5}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=\frac{3}{10}\cdot\sqrt{3}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{3\cdot\sqrt{3}}{5\cdot2}=\frac{3}{10}\cdot\sqrt{3}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{3\cdot\sqrt{3}}{10}=\frac{3}{10}\cdot\sqrt{3}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{3\cdot\sqrt{3}}{10}=\frac{3\cdot\sqrt{3}}{10}$$

Because $2\cdot5=10$.